# configure outgoing mail server return error

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, moodle

I've been using Moodle 3.10.1 and configuring outgoing mail server with there parameters:
SMTP hosts: smtp.gmail.com:465

SMTP security: SSL

SMTP username: my email address @gmail.com

SMTP password: my password for the above email account

but after test out email configuration, Moodle return these errors:

**2021-03-01 08:49:30   Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465, timeout=300, options=array()

2021-03-01 08:49:30 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed [D:\wamp64\www\myweb\lib\phpmailer\src\SMTP.php line 344]

2021-03-01 08:49:30 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto [D:\wamp64\www\myweb\lib\phpmailer\src\SMTP.php line 344]

2021-03-01 08:49:30 Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Unknown error) [D:\wamp64\www\myweb\lib\phpmailer\src\SMTP.php line 344]

2021-03-01 08:49:30 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server:  (0)
2021-03-01 08:49:30 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting**

Please help me to fix error. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you logged into https://account.google.com and:

1. Click on [Security] menu
2. Scroll to section [Less secure app access] and set it to ON
3. Scroll to section [Signing in to Google] and set [Use your phone to sign in] to OFF
4. Scroll to section [Signing in to Google] and set [2-step Verification] to OFF

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did as you instructed but still have the same error. Do I need to install ssl on apache, php?